# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getRandomValues' of undefined or null reference in powerbi.js and powerbi.min.js

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am embedding a PowerBI report in IE using ExtJS .Net, but I am receiving the following console error:

`"Unhandled exception at line 6, column 1859 in http://localhost:55020/scripts/powerbi.min.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getRandomValues' of undefined or null reference"`

```
function getRandomValue() {
    // window.msCrypto for IE
    var cryptoObj = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
    var randomValueArray = new Uint32Array(1);
    cryptoObj.getRandomValues(randomValueArray);
    return randomValueArray[0];
}
```

powerbi-client version 2.10.3

Answer (score 2):

`getRandomValues` is a method of `window.msCrypto` object in IE11, but it is not supported in IE9.
`powerbi-client` library works fine with IE11.

Refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto#Browser_compatibility